# Represent Negative percentage in excel instead of 0.0%

Tags: excel, math, statistics, operators, excel-formula

How can I show negative percent in excel?

I need to find worst case.

**Current Input**

```
if A = 15/19   = 78.9%
   B = 162/268 = 60.4%
   C = 0/5     = 0.0%
   D = 0/90    = 0.0%
```

**Output required.**

FYI `numerator and divisor is coming from another cell`

```
if A = 15/19   = 78.9%
   B = 162/268 = 60.4%
   C = 0/5     = -5.0%
   D = 0/90    = -90%
```

Comment: I don't understand both *I need or similar solution or know which is worst C or D*, and the second table.

Comment: well I came up with getting negative % to find out which is worst C or D, if you think of better way of finding is welcome second table is what I need.

Comment: @Mowgli What do you mean by "worst"? Zero is zero.

Comment: Please see updated question. I need to find out is C worst or D worst.

Comment: Seems like a bit of a math understanding here...

Comment: `0` doesn't give me enough information. if C is worst or D is worst. think of C and D as person who were given number work to do.

Comment: `0/5 = 0/90`, they are the same, if you want to compare them you need to use some sort of weighted analysis rather than percentages.

Comment: @bendataclear Thanks that's what I was kind looking for finding way to  compare worst between two, can you please give me some hints?

Comment: You need to decide how you want it weighted, eg is 1/90 better than 0/5?

Comment: well 1/90 but my case, I can't change data. sorry having bit hardtime understanding. what if I covert it to binary numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding your question but you will only get a negative percentage where one of either the numerator or denominator is below zero:

```
0/5 = 0%
5/5 = 100%
-5/5 = -100%
5/-5 = -100%
```

If you presume we're talking about employees here, comparing the number of tasks assigned versus the number of tasks completed and you want to judge two employees differently even though neither of them accomplished anything you'll have to use something besides percentages.

In your example you imply that 0/5 is different from 0/90 but this would **also** imply that somebody completing 10/20 tasks (50%) should be rated differently from somebody completing 200/400 tasks (also 50%).

Some things you could do are giving each employee some value like 2 points for every task they complete and subtracting 3 points for every task they did not complete.

```
A = (15 *2) - (4  *3) =   18 points
B = (162*2) - (106*3) =    6 points
C = (0  *2) - (5  *3) =  -15 points
D = (0  *2) - (90 *3) = -270 points
```

The problem here is that you would need to decide the weighting, as comments have pointed out, this weighting would give somebody who completed 200/400 tasks less points than somebody who completed 10/20. It looks like you've already decided to go with a modified 'percentage' value so further argument is moot but the weighting would have to be determined based on the meaning behind the numbers.

I'll give one alternative below where 3 points are given for completing a task and 2 are subtracted for failing to complete a task:

```
A = (15 *3) - (4  *2) =   37 points
B = (162*3) - (106*2) =  274 points
C = (0  *3) - (5  *2) =  -10 points
D = (0  *3) - (90 *2) = -180 points
```

Another metric I might consider is to take ALL 205 of the uncompleted tasks and assign percentages based on how many of the uncompleted tasks belong to each user:

```
A =   4 / 205 =   1.9%
B = 106 / 205 =  51.7%
C =   5 / 205 =   2.4%
D =  90 / 205 =  43.9%
```

In this case, you would be ranking whoever has failed to complete the largest percentage of the uncompleted tasks pool.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hinting at, just need to decide how many points each point is worth, do you want to favour completed on incomplete? do they need the same value?

Comment: But if you do +2 and -3, somebody completing 200/400 tasks end up with less points than somebody else completing 10/20 tasks. This should be reverted I think, +3 and -2. Anyway, you get the point there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea, but I think it wouldn't give me more point based on ratio

Comment: Can you please explain, what is idea and how to use 205 method? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing

Cell `A1 = 0.0%`

Then I did following using if else condition.

**Output**
[image: Output]

Formula in D2

```
=IF(IFERROR(C2/B2,"")=$A$1,-B2*0.01,IFERROR(C2/B2,""))
```

[image]

Hope it will help others

Comment: Sorry guys but I really needed percentages.

Comment: This implies that 1/10000 is better than 0/2, right? You might be better with nvuono's answer.